# Woocommerce: Payment gateway custom thank you page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a Woocommerce custom Payment Gateway plugin (it basically redirects the user to the payment service page and then the payment service page redirects the user back to an especified URL), everything is working as expected but I can't seem to create a custom thank-you page **FROM THE PLUGIN**.

What I mean with "from the plugin" is that if someone installs my Payment Gateway plugin they should be able to see the custom thank-you page without any aditional operation like adding a Woocommerce theme or page in WP.

Here is what I'm currently using to handle the default thank-you page:

The redirect URL is given by: `$this->get_return_url($order))`

The thank you page is hooked with:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_'.$this->id, array( $this, 'return_handler' ) );
```

And here is my function that should handle the thankyou page messages:

```
public function return_handler() {
  $order_id = get_query_var('order-received');
  global $woocommerce;
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  //NEXT I JUST CHECK THE ORDER AND SHOW MESSAGES DEPENDING ON THE RESULT
}
```

EDIT: also if there is another way of returning the user to an URL that will trigger one of my plugins function, that could be a valid option.

Answer (score 5):

I *think* the filter you need to target is `woocommerce_payment_successful_result` which is in the `WC_Checkout` class.

```
function so_27024470_paypal_redirect( $return, $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    if( $order->payment_method == 'your-gateway-id' ){
        $return['redirect'] = 'http://your-redirect.com';
    }
    return $return;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_successful_result, 'so_27024470_paypal_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

I haven't tested this, so use at your own risk.

Comment: I couldn't find much reference about that filter/hook, any ideas of  how I trigger it (URL?).

Comment: Since it is in the `process_checkout()` method of the `WC_Checkout` class, I am going to assume that it fires when you are on the checkout page. It should fire when an order is successfully paid.

Comment: Thank for the help :), but that doesn't seem to help with what I'm trying to achieve. I will redirect the user to another page (just like PayPal Express, for example) and then that page will redirect the user back to me. I'm having trouble with displaying a custom message/page out of the box in that "redirect URL" and not triggering a function after the approval :(

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. This redirects you after payment is complete, not off to another site and then back.