# How can we redirect to our custom page after paypal payment

Tags: php, paypal, woocommerce

how to change the redirection page after paypal redirect. Current it redirects to my account page i want to redirect it to my custom page. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642895/setting-paypal-return-url-and-making-it-auto-return

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27033838/383847